# Date picker in tvOS

Tags: swift, datepicker, tvos

Apple has removed date picker from tvOS, is there any alternative? How do i implement date picker for Apple tv. I tried to google but i couldn't get any solution. I tried to work github custom calendar's and date pickers but nothing worked due to absence of some libraries in tvOS.

Any suggestions or reference?

Thanks

Comment: you need to decide what user experience you want first, then create something if you can't find any 3rd party offering that meets your need

Comment: I have used this as base for my need. [tvOS Date](https://www.cleveroad.com/blog/how-to-develop-for-tvos-first-face-to-face-experience)

Comment: thanks, i am looking into that. Any idea on how can we implement popover for tvOS? Do you have any reference for popover as well?

Answer (score 2):

Since Apple does not provide a date picker for tvOS, there is no standard solution.

However, some possible steps would be:

1. Design and implement a UI for manipulating the date components (= year, month, day, hour, minute).
2. Keep track of the currently selected date, e.g. using a stored property. A date label can be updated using property observers (e.g.
   `didSet`).
3. Implement methods for manipulating the selected date - component by component - and connect them to the UI.

Remember that dates and date calculations are complicated(!), so use the provided date concepts and methods - have a look at [Calendar](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar) and `DateComponents` in the documentation.

There, you will find useful methods, for example:

- `range(of: Calendar.Component, in: Calendar.Component, for: Date)`
  can be used to find the number of months in a year, days in a month
  (and so on).
- `dateComponents(Set<Calendar.Component>, from: Date)` and `date(from:
  DateComponents)` can be used to convert from dates to date components
  and vice versa.
- Further, `isValidDate(in: Calendar)` can be useful to check that date
  components form a valid date in a certain calendar.

---

Below is a link to the user interface (with `UISegmentedControl`s) that I developed for my app, however, other solutions are possible.

[User interface with segmented controls.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBd4W.jpg)

In my case, the date picker is presented modally after selecting a table view cell in an input form.